# Awk statement generating extra output line; skip blank input lines

Tags: linux, awk

```
jon,doe          5        5      
sam,smith       10        5
```

I am required to calculate average for row & column. So basically the inputfile contains name score1 and score2 and i am required to read the contents from a file and then calculate average row-wise and column-wise. I am getting the desired result but there is one extra `'0'` that i am getting due to white space i would appreciate if someone could help.

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "name\tScore1\tScore2\tAverage"} {s+=$2} {k+=$3} {print $1,"\t",$2,"\t",$3,"\t",($2+$3)/2} END {print "Average", s/2,k/2}' input.txt
```

This is the output that i am getting-

```
name           Score1  Score2   Average
jon,doe          5        5      5
sam,smith       10        5      7.5
                                 0
Average         7.5       5
```

Comment: are there anybody can explain me why write in such `{s+=$2} {k+=$3}` way?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr it's an assignment. We are storing whatever is in $2 and $3 in s and k respectively

Comment: what i am wondering is why not `{s+=$2; k+=$3}`? it looks weird if no additional merit

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr u can do that as well. I am learning and i guess learning hard way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have an extra empty or blank (all-whitespace) line in your input file.

Adding `NF==0 {next}` as the first pattern-action pair will skip all empty or blank lines and give the desired result.

<sup>`NF==0` only matches if no fields (data) were found in the input line.

The `next` statement skips remaining statements for the current input line (record) and continues processing on the next line (record).</sup>

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "name\tScore1\tScore2\tAverage"} NF==0 {next} {s+=$2} {k+=$3} {print $1,"\t",$2,"\t",$3,"\t",($2+$3)/2} END {print "Average", s/2,k/2}' input.txt
```